# mysql_insert_array is a fatal error

Tags: php

i am trying to insert the contents of the array below into my mysql table into the fields supplied. but i get fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_insert_array();
    any ideas?

```
  <?php

 // Open database here
 $connect = mysql_connect("xxxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx") or         die('Couldn\'t connect to MySQL Server: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("xxxx", $connect ) or die('Couldn\'t Select the database: ' . mysql_error( $connect ));
    // Let's pretend these values were passed by a form
   $_POST['name'] = "Bob Marley";
   $_POST['country'] = "Jamaica";
   $_POST['music'] = "Reggae";
  $_POST['submit'] = "Submit";

  // Insert all the values of $_POST into the database table `artists`, except
  // for $_POST['submit'].  Remember, field names are determined by array keys!
  $result = mysql_insert_array("artists", $_POST, "submit");

  // Results
    if( $result['mysql_error'] ) {
    echo "Query Failed: " . $result['mysql_error'];
      } else {
    echo "Query Succeeded! <br />";
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
     echo "</pre>";
    }

   // Close database

     ?>
```

Answer (score 7):

`mysql_insert_array` is not a PHP function and therefore cannot be called.

You should be using `mysql_query` instead to insert your array. Alternatively, you should really be using the [mysql_pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) libraries as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: +1, also...inserting $_POST directly into the database without any validation, and not using a newer library like PDO, you are incredibly vulnerable to injection.  Don't ever trust your users, we are a bunch assholes.

Comment: it looks like he was reading up on this tutorial from 2007, fyi: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/inserting-an-array-into-a-mysql-database-table